# is it possible to add nfc ntag216 serial number to url registry?

Tags: nfc

I have some NFC tags (NTAG216) every tag has a unique serial number, I want to use this tags as a user login token so it most be unique in some way. The tags have a single record with a link like so "https://www.example.com?t=DAFDSAG" I want to add a parameter to that GET with the tag serial number, something like "https://www.example.com?t=DAFDSAG&s={serial number}".

If the serial number of the tag is stored at addr 00 and 01, is it possible to have a record with "https://www.example.com?t=DAFDSAG&s={addr 00 and addr 01}" ? meaning that all tags will have a unique url created based on the serial number.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible see Section 8.7.1 of https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

Just write the default Ndef URL to the Tag e.g. `https://www.example.com?t=DAFDSAG&s=00000000000000`

You just configure the mirror option to replace the blocks containing the zero with the UID

Note the UID should never be used for an security or login process as it is very unsecure, as it is so easy to copy and fake the UID, especially using the UID mirror option.

A NFC UID is only designed to prevent card clash when 2 cards are in range.